# Loading php file and then run function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass some parameters to a php file and then load it on my page. After I do that I need to run a function. My problem is that jQuery runs the function before it loads the php file. I can get it working by adding a delay to my function using

```
    setTimeout(function() {
        addSet(id);
    }, 500);
```

Instead I want it to run when my load function is done running. I have tried using $('#exer'+id).ready(function() { with no luck.

This is my code

```
function addExercise(id, name, type, factor, desc) {
        $("<div id='exer"+id+"' class='exer'>lala</div>").insertAfter("#beforeExercises");
        var php_file = "modules/ExerciseSearchTest2/addExercise.php?id="+ id + "&name=" + name + "&type=" + type + "&factor=" + factor + "&desc=" + desc;
        $("#exer"+id).load(encodeURI(php_file));

        addSet(id);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.load()` accepts a callback function to be fired only after the load has been completed.

```
$("#exer"+id).load(encodeURI(php_file), function(){
  //this is the callback function, run your code here.
  addSet(id);
});
```